# How to create inst/ext subdirectory in R package?

Tags: r, package

New R package developer. How can one create inst/extdata subdirectory. I have genomic .rData and want to save it as .rda under the inst/extdata.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Creating a directory? Use your operating system's file explorer to make the directory or the command line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `usethis::use_data` using the `usethis` package.